# Django queries: return a Q object that will translate to "AND (...)"

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-q

I am writing a simple search for our website, and I need to filter the entries on a number of criteria. However, if the strictest filtering is not satisfied, I want to return the results for a less strict search. To that end, I want to create a number of query objects, each with one more filter, then iterate them backwards trying to get a result, and return the first one I get this way.

What I am doing is:

```
q0 = MyIndex.objects.in_city(city_id)
q1 = q0.filter(name_contains(words))
```

where

```
def name_contains(words):
    if not words:
        return Q()
    query = Q(words_contains=words[0])
    for word in word[1:]:
        query = query | Q(words_contains=word)
```

When I pass the words that are not present in the database, I still get a result, because the query part returned by the `name_contains` is attached via `OR` and not `AND`.

Is there a way I can return that query so that it is always attached to the rest of the query by `AND`?

Comment: replace `|` by `&`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I need the parts within this query to be joined by " or". That is, I need the query to end up like "... where city_id=3 and (words like "%one%" or words like "%two%)"

Comment: unless your `in_city` filter has some very weird logic, it will already perform such query. You can investigate this by printing `print(str(MyIndex.objects.in_city(city_id).filter(name_contains(words)).query))`.

Comment: Can you post the code for the manager with your `in_city` reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your have a strange object manager, the `in_city` probably wraps to a `.filter(..)`.

If you chain multiple `.filter(..)`s, then you have implicitly written a logical **and** in between, since your first `filter(..)` virtually already removes the elements that do not satisfy the requirement, and your second filter only filters more.

You can verify this suspicion, by printing the underlying query Django will perform with:

```
print(str(q0.filter(name_contains(words)).query))
```

Note that you can make your function more declarative like:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

def name_contains(words):
    if words:
        return reduce(or_, (Q(word_contains=word) for word in words))
    else:
        return Q()
```

Comment: I need the parts within this query to be joined by " or". That is, I need the query to end up like "... where city_id=3 and (words like "%one%" or words like "%two%)"

Comment: Upon closer inspection of my code i realised, that instead of passing a __list__ of words, I passed a word, and, with strings being iterable, the word was split into chars and thus i got wrong results.

Comment: @Ibolit: ah yes, a string is an iterable of characters as well. Which - unfortunately - frequently leads to errors :s.